# Very basic strtok program misusing delimiters - C

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

Here is my program (written in C, compiled and run on Omega, if it makes any difference):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char string[] = " hello!how are you? I am fine.";
    char *token = strtok(string,"!?.");

    printf("Token points to '%c'.\n",*token);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
"Token points to '!'."
```

But the output I'm getting is:

```
"Token points to ' '."
```

From trial and error, I know this is referring to the first character in the string: the space before "hello!".

Why am I not getting the output I'm expecting, and how can I fix it? I do understand from what I've read on here already that strtok is better off buried in a ditch, but let's assume that (if it's possible) I have to use it here, and I have to make it work.

Comment: Perhaps you should read more about [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and what it returns? Perhaps you want [`strpbrk`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) instead?

Comment: ... and what is does.

Comment: Oh and never forget to *always* check for a `NULL` pointer return.

Comment: Use `strpbrk()` instead of `strtok()`

Answer (score 0):

As per `strtok` man page description

> The strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens. On
>   the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified
>   in str. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, str
>   should be NULL.

It parses the string based on delimiter and return you the string not the delimiter.

In your case delimiters are `"!?."`

```
char string[] = " hello!how are you? I am fine.";
```

First occurrence of the delimiter `"!"` match after the string `" hello"`. So it will return `" hello"` as return of `strtok`. And your output is nothing but first character `' '` of the `" hello"` string.

Answer (score -1):

Someone just posted an answer. It worked for me and now I can't find it. Reposting as best I remember in case someone else has the same question.

```
char *token = strtok(string,"!?.");
token = strtok(NULL, "!?."); //<--THIS
```

token points to the first letter after the first delimiter, which is at least something I can work with. Thank you stranger!